# Minimum distance between 2 times on clock board

Tags: algorithm, distance

Given 2 times (as `int`) on clock board, I have to calculate the minimum distance between them.

[image]

For example  -

```
d(12,1) = 1 //not 11 
d(3,5) = 2 
d(10,10) = 0
```

What is the fastest way for that ?

Comment: I saw a similar problem but involved the minutes, given input is like a list of string, like"23:59", "00:00", also ask for the minimum distance as minute(1, not 1439)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `a` and `b` are from `1` to `12`:

```
min(abs(a - b), 12 - abs(a - b))
```

Answer (score 2):

What have you tried?

```
Dim dif = Math.Abs((t2 + 6) Mod 12 - (t1 + 6) Mod 12)
```

Answer (score 1):

Pure arithmetic (without any libraries):

```
int d(int first, int second){
   int temp = first - second;
   temp < 0? temp *=-1 :temp ;

   int distance = temp > 6? 12-temp:temp;

   return distance;
}
```